ktor library not support buil.gradel version 7.4.1
I am learning the Ktor library and have encountered an issue related to its compatibility with Android Studio Dolphin. I have come across an error message stating, "val cannot be reassigned," and I am uncertain about how to resolve this issue.
Is the Ktor library fully supported in Android Studio Dolphin and how to address the mentioned error?
I am trying to learn ktor library and setup new project.

The error message, "val cannot be reassigned," does not relate to Ktor, but to Kotlin. You have declared a variable (somewhere) with val and are trying to alter it's value. If you need to declare a variable that it's value changes, try using var instead of val. Documentation reference.

thanks but .it's coming from Gradle plugin version

Please share the code this error originates from.
